# Why am I getting an error "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets" in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, ios-provisioning

I installed the Xcode 6 GM seed, and I'm trying to create an IPA file for the first time. After archive success, when I click on the Export button, a window appears saying:

> **Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets**
>
> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.
>
> - **Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate.**
>
>   If you have your signing identity on another Mac, you can import a developer profile. You can also revoke the current certificate and request one again.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: nothing works for me :( is the only option to download xcode 5 ?

Comment: Oddly enough, "Try Again" worked for me

Comment: Sadly no definitive solution or fix. Does anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: i also face same problem xcode 7.2 but not get solution

Answer (score 24):

In keychain access, -> Show Expired Certificates, then in your login keychain click on expired certificate and delete it. I also had the same expired certificate in my System keychain, so I deleted it from there too.

-> After deleting the expired cert from the login and System keychains,download certificate from below link and open with keychain.

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates (which expires on 2023)

this solved my problem

Comment: The download in this solution is what solved it for me. All my certificates where reported as invalid user before I downloaded this.

Comment: Thanks for this post! It fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else: you don't need to delete all expired development certificates, just the Apple "Worldwide Developer Relations" Cert

Comment: Worked for me.
Has everyone who experienced this problem had their developer license expire before renewing?  That's my case, was just curious about others.

Comment: This helped because my problem was my Keychain Access had both the old expired certificate versions and the new versions of the same certificate.  Once I deleted the expired ones, it found the newer ones fine.

Answer (score 21):

I edited distribution profile and downloaded it again, restarted xcode and it worked.

Comment: Same here, just re-saved a new profile, installed it, and then restarted.  Once I did this everything worked.

Comment: I just chose it in the list of provisioning profiles in the Member Center, selected edit, didn't change anything and saved.

Comment: I revoke and create a new distribution profile, download, add to xcode and work like a charm :)

Answer (score 10):

I have been searching answer for this problem past 6 hours. Nothing is satisfactory. As no one knows why this is happening. 
Following is way to generate .ipa via command line. If that works I will update here tomorrow.

> xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Provisioning Profile Name"

Note : The "Provisioning Profile Name" is the name specified in the name field of the certificate (viewable from developer.apple.com).

This will create .ipa.

credit goes to Orginal author [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901269/xcode-attempted-to-locate-or-generate-matching-signing-assets-and-failed-to-do-s)

This trick worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same thing the first time, and then I realized that in the dev site there was a new provisioning profile that started with XC:
I restarted xcode and xcode automatically found the XC: profile it created earlier and allowed me to sign the app.
It looked as if the restart of xcode and refresh of signatures (after signing in while uploading/verifying the app on xcode) did the trick

Comment: restarted the Xcode and it works. even In Xcode 10!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when having multiple development accounts/teams I was on.  The solution for me was to make sure that all of the following were properly set up:

1. I had a distribution certificate with private key for the account
   the app belonged to (if someone else has made the certificate you have to key the private key from them and install it).
2. I had a specific (not wildcard) application ID
   (as in com.mycompany.myapp).
3. I had a provisioning profile that was
   created using the distribution certificate mentioned above along
   with the AppID mentioned above.

When all of that is in place, you can refresh your account in Xcode and you should not get that message anymore...

Answer (score 2):

This must be an issue with the team you have selected. If you have created a new bundle id from some other apple account which is not added in your `xcode` preferences follow the below steps to add new team.

```
Step 1: Go to xcode preference.
Step 2: Click on Accounts tab.
Step 3: Click on (+) icon to add new account.
Step 4: Login with developer account credential
Step 5: Click on 'Done'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why 'Use local signing assets' worked for me

Comment: Same here. The thing is, When you choose the team, Xcode tries to figure out the signing "setup" by requesting the Developer Portal. And for some unknown reason it fails to do so. The last resort in this case would be to use local signing assets. Of course, if you are 100% sure, you have the correct "setup" locally already.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by renaming the provisioning profile name in member center and refreshing in XCode 6.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue. I was pretty sure about my provisioning and certificate etc are properly set. I created all these at apple dev portal while my **Xcode 6.2** was opened. After downloading certificate and provisioning, I double clicked both and then was able to choose for signing from Xcode. That is **NO Xcode restart needed up-to this point** as new provisioning file is available to be chosen from Xcode. Then I archived the binary and it opened in Organizer for submission.

But here comes the actual issue that **Organiser** is not aware about my true assets. So, here we need to **restart** the Organiser (Xcode). I must say a bug at Apple's end to not make Organiser aware about the updated assets. As after restarting the Organiser, I submitted the app and it **prompted to allow to sign certificate from Keychain**.

Answer (score 1):

Only this way solved the issue for me:
Open the "Keychain Access" app and select "View" -> "Show Expired Certificates". Remove ALL expired Apple certificates! 
Restart Xcode.

See: Xcode unable to create distribution builds for App Store submissions or Enterprise apps -> https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when using Xcode 6 GM and so I used Xcode 5.1 to create the ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when attempting the first release with a new Xcode version *on the same Mac*.

In my case I had both Xcode 6 and Xcode 5 installed.

I solved the issue by exporting my .developerprofile in Xcode 5 and then importing it in Xcode 6 as follows:

### In old Xcode (mine was 5.1.1)

1. Go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts
2. Select Gear icon in bottom left
3. Select Export Accounts
4. Set the file to save in a place you'll find easily
5. Enter password that you'll use when importing
6. Select Save

### In new Xcode (mine was 6.0.1)

1. Go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts
2. Select Gear icon in bottom left
3. Select Import Accounts
4. Select the .developerprofile file
5. Enter the password and you will now be able to continue.

---

This works from old Mac to new Mac as well.

Comment: Where would I import from when there is no earlier developer profile ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you only have developer's certificate in your Keychain, you can't export Ad Hoc builds. You must have a distribution certificate as well as a distribution provision profile

Answer (score 0):

For me, all I had to do was restart XCode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In XCODE 6 when we create a provisioning profile it should be of type ADHOC.Set the profile in build settings and then archive.Everything will work fine I guess

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and now i can EXPORT my App again. 
1) this reply was very funny but good  NOT TO HEAR ANYONE combining with 
2) answered Sep 19 '14 at 23:21 
hepled me to get work on my iPhone.

Go to development.apple.com -> Certificates -> All / Production and just delete you **iOS Distribution** thing. It could be so that you deleted all certificates local and it does not match the original anymore thats why you have this message with this image =)  As i said i had the same problem. After deleting just Archive and Export new and it will do this for you automaticly.

**Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)**

Answer (score 0):

I could see my Distribution certificate in the keychain, but it was unsigned.  I solved this by going to the Dev site, clearing out all certificates and provisioning profiles (yes, deleting all), and re-gen the certificates (dev and dist) and download and clearing old certs and importing new into keychain.  Also if you have more than one app ID, generate the distribution profile and download in import else Xcode mgmgt may choose the wrong app to create the profile (happened to me).  Restarting XCode, I made sure that the iOS Distribution was chosen in my apps Target signing section (it was not).   XCode remade the prov-profiles for me.   It passed signing validation (ugh now on to 64-bit support!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case "Xcode 7.3" all i needed was to clean the project, restart Xcode, re-archive and it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem at my end was, in itunesconnect my account was certified as "iOS developer" but not as "iOS app distributor". Had to recreate certificate, download it, open with keychain , and then revalidate the archive. It finally worked. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to disable Automatic signing management in Target > General and import both dev and pro profiles after downloading them from my Apple dev account.
Rebuilt app and it worked, nothing else did. I guess this issue can come from many different sources.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by something different, so this might be able to help.

Its quite simple, I have to dev accounts and I chose the wrong one when Exporting on the organizer! Duh.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Don't listen to anyone.

DO NEXT:

1. Open XCODE
2. Go to Xcode > Preferences > View Details
3. You will see Signing Identifies at the top of new opened window. There will be "iOS Development" or "iOS Distribution". (in my case there was only 1 - iOS Development)
4. Revoke all Signing Identifies you have there
5. Click "+" button and click "iOS Development" then "iOS Distribution". Now you are requesting new identifies!

FINISH! ONLY 5 STEPS

Comment: I like your confidence but this was as fail as other answers.

Comment: This was scary.  I got an email saying my development certificate has been revoked.  Admittedly, I don't really know what I am doing in xcode, but I can't recommend this to anyone, just in case it really does something bad.

Comment: This is a dangerous answer as it's not necessarily addressing the issue, and for people who work in team environments, it's very likely that you don't want to revoke all Signing Identities. Do not follow this suggestions unless you absolutely understand what you're doing.

Comment: We had to burn the village to save the people.