# Xcode 6 - failed to locate or generate matching signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

**Error:**

> Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do
>   so because of the following issues:

**No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/myapp.app"**

*None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups.*

While trying to distribute a company / in-house app:

I've upgraded from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 and now my normal routine results in the above error. How to fix this? Tried renaming the distribution profile, restarting Xcode, letting Xcode generate it's own files, creating a new distribution certificate. What now?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862917/failed-to-locate-or-generate-matching-signing-assets-in-xcode-6

Comment: No, this is a different error.

Comment: Did you found any solution to the problem ?

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to export an old archive, which I cannot recreate, for ad-hoc. Have tried everything. This seems to be something new in xCode 6. I think maybe I deleted something I need... how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the Architectures setting. I assume this was just a problem with Architectures/Valid Architectures being incompatible with one another.

Comment: Profile has no relation with Architectures

Answer (score -5):

After searching and trying many ways, my problem is resolved by first Product->Clean, then Archive again for validate/submit. Sounds a bit trivial, not sure if this can solve your problem.