# Failed to locate or generate matching singing assets:When i'm triyng to generate ad hoc ipa

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipa, codesign

Anyone can help me.Actually i'm 6 month kid for ios app development,this is my first app to submit in appstore.When i'm trying to generate the ad_hoc distribution IPA,it shows error(as like the below screenshot).But for appstore IPA generated successfully,i'm so confused.....what a magic this!

[image]

I have tried the follwing things **To solve this problem**:

1.Deleted all my mac keychain certificates.
2.Delete all xcode caches and and provisioning profiles and also deleted the developer account from xcode.

and restarted my mac...
then,

1.Reinstalled the certifcates in keychain from exported **.P12** from another mac

2.login in xcode preferences accounts tab.... and refresh it. it downlods all provisioning profiles from my developer account.

**Status:** Not working,still the same issue....all of another projects of my mac and appstore ipa too.

Even i have generated new developer certificate and updated all my project provisioning profiles.still have the same issue...,then try with it new bundle id and new provisioning profiles..i can't got it!

Bcoz of this problem i can't generete ipa for allof another app from my mac..for this issue i wasted entirely 2 working days.totally disturbed.....

Once i solve this then only i can sleep well.pls help me ,thanks in advance to you....

Comment: Have u created separate distribution certificate for App Store not adhoc distribution.

Comment: But in another person mac, same app i can generate the ipa,for my mac..i can't

Comment: yes,i have generate new distribution certificate too,entire things are new(bundle id,developer and distribution certficates and provisioning profiles)....

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862917/why-am-i-getting-an-error-failed-to-locate-or-generate-matching-signing-assets

Comment: ya exactly the same link i refered and process yesterday...

Comment: hi,in this link  (   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH9-SW1  ) how do i process the 4th step as .developerprofile extension,may i know pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having same trouble few weeks back. Though I haven't yet figured out the exact issue behind it but I found that exporting an .ipa file via commandline works.

1. Archive your project using your desired build settings.
2. Locate the .xarchive file in finder (**DON'T follow the usual procedure from this point**).
3. Copy it and paste it to your project directory (Where your .xcodeproj file is). (Though I usually rename it to remove all the spaces from the name as well)
4. `cd` to your project directory in terminal
5. Run following Command:

---

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive  -archivePath  YourArchiveName.xcarchive -exportPath YourIpaName.ipa   -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile YOUR_PROVISION_PROFILE_NAME
```

Your .ipa file will be generated in your project directory. Use it as you will.

For example if My archive name was `mySillyApp` and I wanted to create an ad hoc ipa from it named `mySillyApp` with provisioning profile named `MySillyProfile`, I'd run it like this

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive  -archivePath  mySillyApp.xcarchive -exportPath mySillyApp.ipa   -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile MySillyProfile
```

**NOTE:** Even though this doesn't fix the issue of xcode but it gets the ipa. Just thought it would help someone looking for a quick way to get the ad hoc build, who doesn't have the time to figure out what's wrong with Xcode.

Comment: Thanks a lot  NSNoob,its working fine.how can i generate the appstore ipa like this manner.

Comment: Archive using desired credentials, get the archive, do same steps. Just make sure you mention your app store provisioning profile in terminal command.

Comment: Thanks a lot NSNOOB,its perfect  :)

Comment: Not really mate. More like a tape fix. You may have noticed that even though this generates ipa faster than usual way but the resulting ipa takes more size than usual ipa. Somewhat like 20% increase in MBs. Somehow compression doesn't work well with cmdline build. Which is why you shouldn't be content with this way and find the real issue. I will update the answer if I do as well.

Comment: But i have a doubt,How it works smartly and why the usual procedure is not working....let me know

Answer (score 0):

> If you are doing this for distribution environment, and previously if you
>   have already created the distribution certificate from different mac then
>
> - Either export that same certificate from that mac and import it here or
> - Revoke the same certificate from your mac, that will be then added to your key chain (https://help.como.com/hc/en-us/articles/201708891-Revoke-Your-iOS-Distribution-Certificate-P12-File-)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

After doing this just restart your XCode and give try

Hope this will help you!